# Which languages marks grammatically for social relationships?

Tags: grammar, sociolinguistics, list-of-languages

Which languages apart from Japanese, Korean and Javanese encode systematically the relationships between speaker, hearer and referent by means of grammar markers and special sets of vocabulary?

Comment: In Manchu there are about 20 words for 'I' depending on who the speaker and the listener(s) are. Generally speaking, this feature of marking politeness is the areal feature of most of the languages of Pacific Asia.

Comment: most of the languages of pacific asia? would it be still most of the languages of this area if only grammatical realisation would count?

Comment: Does the choice of personal pronouns according to social relationships count as "grammatical realisation"?

Comment: I do not know, as limited as i know grammatical realisation is either realization by syntax or realization by morphology. as i understand it, pronouns are lexical realizations.

Comment: In Javanese the realisation of social relationships is also purely lexical. You need to formulate your questions better before asking them.

Comment: how sure are you about javanese?

Comment: Are you kidding? Have you ever read a grammar of Javanese? It's like Malay, no inflectional morfology, only the choice of words shows social relationships.

Comment: wikipedia says: " There is a complex system of verb affixes to express differences of status in subject and object"

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: Would languages with a [T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) qualify? To a lesser extent, what about [majestic plural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)? Heck, what about how in formal English people seem to prefer Latin roots over Germanic?

Comment: Also, I have some experience with Korean and the phenomenon you're describing seems to be morphological, not grammatical. I.e. the inclusion or exclusion of the 시 particle does not change the grammatic structure of the sentence.

Comment: Morphology is not part of grammar anymore? \-:

Comment: @hippietrail Depends how you define grammar. I've seen people define it as syntax and I've seen people define it as morphosyntax. In retrospect, morphosyntax is probably a more common definition and I had simply suffered a brain fart.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoidance_speech

Answer (score 2):

Various Australian Aboriginal languages have grammatical encoding of the kinship relationships between speaker/hearer/referent.

See:
Blythe, Joe (2013), [Preference organization driving structuration: Evidence from Australian Aboriginal interaction for pragmatically motivated grammaticalization](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24671960). Language, 89:4, pp. 883-919.